# Orion broker & node red

Tags: node-red, fiware-orion

My purpose is to **query the context** on Orion broker with a node-red flow.

In a Node-RED function node I set my json format query on the msg.payload property.

On headers When I set `'Content-Type':'application/json'` header I get an error:

`"Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"`

So I remove this header but then I get a reply about

`"JSON parse error"`

and

`connection: "close" content-length: "0" allow: "POST"`.

My json query on payload is valid as validator says.

Answer (score 1):

Finally,this **very simple  "issue"** is because of **my fault** that i hadn't noticed that the `msg.method` is of type `GET` instead of `POST` which is the suitable.